# how to stop adding a row if error occurs apex salesforce

Tags: apex

I want to stop the code to add another row if there is an error. Currently the code is displaying the error and also adding another row simultaneously.

How to put an check.

```
public void addRows() {

    Integer countIndex = 0;
    Set<Integer> indexSet = new Set<Integer>();
    for (AccountWrapper wrapper: wrappers){
        if(wrapper.acc.StartDate__c< date.valueof(date.today())){
            indexSet .add(countIndex );
        }
        countIndex ++;

        for(Integer count : indexSet) {
            wrappers[count].startdateErrorMessage ='An error occurred';
        }

    }
    wrappers.add(new AccountWrapper(nextIdent++));

}
```

Comment: what is the logic to add error?

Comment: if(wrapper.acc.StartDate__c< date.valueof(date.today())) ... is the logic..

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code as

```
for(AccountWrapper wrapper: wrappers) { 
    if(wrapper.acc.StartDate__c < date.valueof(date.today())) {
        indexSet .add(countIndex );
    }
    countIndex ++;

}
for(Integer count : indexSet) {
    wrappers[count].startdateErrorMessage ='An error occurred';
}

if(indexSet.size() == 0) {
    wrappers.add(new AccountWrapper(nextIdent++));
}
```

It will not add row if you have any error.